# Get facebook pages ID (Scraping)

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm trying to build an application to gather some posts from specific public pages on Facebook. I know how can i collect the required info if I have the UID of the page i'm looking for. But i need a way to **excract facebook pages (not people) within certain filters** (for example: Country, page type, amount of likes, etc). Any tip of reference would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, and there is no api for what you want to achieve. in other words: it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Facebook page you own/admin > “About” > “Page Info.” Now, at the very bottom, you can find the “Facebook Page ID”.

I have found a website that may work. Go to https://findmyfbid.com/ it may help!

Comment: That would be great, but the pages i'm looking information are not mine. Just public pages

Comment: ups.. Ok.. Searching internet.. Coming back if I get any help

Comment: Do you need to fetch the page id automatically or this will help?

Comment: I need to search, for example: Get all facebook page from Chile, local bussiness, some other filters, and bla bla
I could be the name or the id, i don't care, i could process that info later, but i need a list of pages, that's all.

Comment: Woo! that's can be harder to get!

Comment: I'll do that, i really want to do this programatically. I'm coming back with an answer later :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150025/discussion-between-jaturna-and-thrasher).